# Tomcat 8.5 memory

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

I have a rest webservice on Tomcat 8.5 with jdk1.8.0_171. I executed the webservice by browser (e.g. mozilla) but it doesn't show the json output. Well the json output is considered big by for Tomcat/Java.

So on tomcat/bin/catalina.sh file I added:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $JSSE_OPTS -Xms256m -Xmx1024m"
```

Besides the file contains:

```
if [ -z "$JSSE_OPTS" ] ; then
  JSSE_OPTS="-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048"
fi
```

Additionally, tomcat server status shows:
Free memory: 139.46 MB Total memory: 247.56 MB Max memory: 989.87 MB

```
Memory Pool     Type             Initial    Total      Maximum      Used
Eden Space      Heap memory     68.31 MB    68.37 MB    273.06 MB   28.33 MB (10%)
Survivor Space  Heap memory     8.50 MB     8.50 MB     34.12 MB    4.90 MB (14%)
Tenured Gen     Heap memory     170.68 MB   170.68 MB   682.68 MB   74.84 MB (10%)
Code Cache      Non-heap memory 2.43 MB     36.00 MB    240.00 MB   35.52 MB (14%)
Compressed Class Space  
                Non-heap memory 0.00 MB     11.87 MB    1024.00 MB  11.10 MB (1%)
Metaspace   Non-heap memory     0.00 MB     92.62 MB    -0.00 MB    88.85 MB
```

Spring mvc is used to generate json output which size is 334273 characters. There's no error in code (Java Exception)

So What is missing in this case? How can I increase the memory usage for rest services?. In my local pc works well with the same service/war and logic

Regards

Comment: What does *"json output is considered big"* mean? Do you get an error? If so, edit the question and show it.

Comment: Why do you think it is a memory issue?

Comment: How are you generating the JSON? How big is it really? If huge, have you considered using *streaming* to generate the JSON?

Comment: Add maxHttpHeaderSize="100000" in server.xml. I hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

On server test we have more than 6gb RAM, so I supposed the quantity of memory heap is not assigned on Java as it should be.

Then, I added maxHttpHeaderSize and removed -Xms256m -Xmx1024m on Tomcat configuration and it works after doing tests.

So the reason of the fail was the maximum size of response HTTP header and not the memory as I thought.